# Python lista arredondamento

Tags: python, lista, arredondamento

```
a = [1.2,2.3,3.4]
b = [4.1,5.2,6.3]
x = 3.4
y = a.index(x)
print (y)
y1 = b[y]
print (y1)
```

Como eu faria no código se x fosse 3. sendo que eu queria que fosse mostrado o valor mais próximo. no caso se x = 3, y iria receber a posição 2 ou seja 3.4

Comment: Já ouviu falar de busca binária (binary search)?

Answer (score 1):

Vejo que tanto a lista ´a´ como ´b´ estão ordenadas.

Assumindo que todas as listas para o qual pertende testar estejam também ordenadas o que recomendo é fazer uma pesquisa binária por o valor mais proximo.

A minha sugestão é a seguinte:

```py
def binary_search_closest(l, item):
    last = len(l) - 1
    mid = last // 2

    if l[mid] == item:
        return mid

    else:
        if last == 1:  # apenas 2 elementos
            if abs(l[0] - item) < abs(l[1] - item):
                return 0
            else:
                return 1
        elif item < l[mid]:
            return binary_search_closest(l[:mid + 1], item)  # incluir o l[mid] para o caso de arredondamento
        else:
            return mid + binary_search_closest(l[mid:], item)
```

Caso as listas não se encontrem ordenadas apenas surgiro percorrer a lista toda e ir guardando o indice do mais proximo, assim como a sua diferença em relação ao item.

A minha soluçao:

```py
def find(l, item):
    closest = (0, abs(item - l[0]))  # tuplo com indice do valor mais proximo e a sua diferença em relação ao item
    for i in range(len(l)):
        dif = abs(item - l[i])
        if dif == 0:  # se encontrou o item na lista
            return i
        elif dif < closest[1]:
            closest = (i, dif)

    return closest[0]
```

Note que neste caso se existirem 2 elementos da lista com a mesma diferença apenas retornará o indice do primeiro que aparecer.

Por exemplo em: `a=[1.0, 2.5, 3.5]` se pesquisar pelo valor 3 ele irá retornar o indice 1, para o valor 2.5

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite!

Tenta fazer desta forma: 
* precisa importar a biblioteca numpy

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1.2,2.3,3.4])
b = np.array([4.1,5.2,6.3])

x = 3.0

idx = (np.abs(a-x)).argmin()
print(idx)
```